# bootstrap date picker based on timezone dynamically

Tags: javascript, datetime, bootstrap-datepicker

I am developing an application where survey module requires the date picker to be opened dynamically based on the timezone where the shipper is staying.

For instance, the data operator is living in California and is filling up a form for a customer, who is in Australia. So the date picker should open the calendar relevant to Australian timezone.

I couldn't find relevant results for how should I do this using Bootstrap date picker.

Comment: so, what have you tried so far in terms of coding?

Comment: Depending on the datetime picker library you are using, there will usually be a way to set a default date. There is then the library moment.js which handles all this local time stuff and most of the datetime pickers I have come across accept moments in their default date fields, so you can use that to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle should be enough to get you started, it follows on from my comment to your original question.

https://jsfiddle.net/gqc1c3r6/

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new moment()
  });
});
```

Docs for the library used can be found here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: This shows datepicker in local time but how do we show in UTC time format?